# How to draw revolved disk shape using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Is there an elegant way to rotate this shape about the axis and draw in 3D? Ideally I would like to be able to draw a revolved view of this as 180 deg, 270 deg and the full revolution at 360 deg.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \scalex {0.02};
\def \scaley {0.02};

%Input Variables
\def \DA {1000};
\def \EL {200};
\def \TM {20};
\def \HA {25};
\def \HI {60};
\def \DN {500};
\def \DS {325};
\def \BN {100};
\def \N {-4.026};
\def \S {1.342 };

%Draw shell
\draw (-\HA/2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley - \TM*\scaley) -- (-\EL /2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley -     \TM*\scaley) --  (-\EL /2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley)  --  (\EL /2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley) -- (\EL /2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley - \TM*\scaley) -- (\HA/2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley - \TM*\scaley); 

% Draw hub
\draw (-\HI/2*\scalex, \DN/2*\scaley) --  (-\BN/2*\scalex, \DN/2*\scaley) -- (-\BN/2*\scalex, \DS/2*\scaley) -- (\BN/2*\scalex, \DS/2*\scaley) -- (\BN/2*\scalex, \DN/2*\scaley) -- (\HI/2*\scalex, \DN/2*\scaley) ;

% Draw disk
\draw[scale=0.02,domain=\DN/2:\DA/2 - \TM, variable=\r, black ] plot ({-\HA/2*(( \r/ (\DA/2 - \TM))^(-\N/3))}, {\r} );
\draw[scale=0.02,domain=\DN/2:\DA/2 - \TM, variable=\r, black ] plot ({\HA/2*(( \r/ (\DA/2 - \TM))^(-\N/3))}, {\r} );

% Draw centerline
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0);

% Draw labels
\draw (-\HA/2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley - \TM*\scaley) -- ++ (-1,-1) node [left] {a};
\draw (\HA/2*\scalex, \DA/2*\scaley - \TM*\scaley) -- ++ (1,-1) node [right] {b};
\draw (-\HI/2*\scalex, \DN/2*\scaley)  -- ++ (-1, 1) node [left] {c};
\draw (\HI/2*\scalex, \DN/2*\scaley)  -- ++ ( 1, 1) node [right] {d};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: These type of tasks are really for Asymptote :)

Comment: `￼\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}` may works ... as long as you can rewrite your contour using a function.

Comment: As far as I know there is a separate scripting language called _sketch4latex_ that seems to be very powerful for 3D pictures. It compiles a sketch file to generate TikZ code, which is then processed by LaTeX. Unfortunately I can't tell you more about sketch since I have never used it before.

Comment: Your code does not give the figure you say it does. (You've switched the numerator and denominator in the function.)

Comment: Do you want to be able to see the inside?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an Asymptote solution (somewhat imperfect; the inside surface could be constructed more precisely, for a slightly better result). The construction of surfaces of revolution is explained in [my tutorial](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf).

[image: hollow surface of revolution]

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=8;
import graph3;
size(10cm);

currentprojection = orthographic((10,4,2), showtarget=false);

real DA = 1000;
real EL = 200;
real TM = 20;
real HA = 25;
real HI = 60;
real DN = 500;
real DS = 325;
real BN = 100;
real N = -4.026;
real S = 1.342;

// Construct shell (right side only)
path shell = (0, DA/2) -- (EL/2, DA/2) -- (EL/2, DA/2 - TM) -- (HA/2, DA/2 - TM);

// Construct hub (right side only)
path hub = (0, DS/2) -- (BN/2, DS/2) -- (BN/2, DN/2) -- (HI/2, DN/2);

// Construct disk (right side only)
path disk = graph(new pair(real r) { return (HA/2*(( (DA/2 - TM) / r)^(-N/3)), r); },
          DN/2, DA/2-TM);

// Put them together. The shell has to be reversed so that it goes
// from bottom to top.
path wholepath = hub & disk & reverse(shell);

// Now, construct the "inside" surface (so that it can be a different color).
pair inside(real l) {
  real t = arctime(wholepath, l);
  pair offset = scale(1.0) * rotate(90) * dir(wholepath, t);
  return point(wholepath, t) + offset;
}
path insidepath = graph(inside, 0, arclength(wholepath), n=200);

// Put it in the YZ plane.
path3 wholepath3 = path3(wholepath, YZplane);
path3 insidepath3 = path3(insidepath, YZplane);

// Revolve the path from 0 degrees to 270 degrees.
surface revolution = surface(wholepath3, c=(0,0,0), axis=Z, angle1=0, angle2=270);
surface insidesurface = surface(insidepath3, c=(0,0,0), axis=Z, angle1=0, angle2=270);

// And now draw it.
draw(revolution, surfacepen=blue);
draw(insidesurface, surfacepen=white);
```

Comment: When he said "the axis" I thought it meant a different axis, namely the line at the bottom of the figure he provided, not "its axis" as in your interpretation.  Nice drawing though.

Answer (score 2):

http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/ is good at rotating arbitrary shapes.  It can generate TikZ code.

Here's a snippet from the manual for drawing a helix:

```
  % define a "polyline", in this case a single vector literal
  def K [0,0,1]
  sweep[cull=false] {
    % trace out 60 segments
    60,
    % rotating each of the segments
    % ... note, however, for your use case you would need
    % to rotate around a different point
    rotate(10, (0,0,0), [K]) then translate(1/6 * [K]) 
    % ... and you don't need the translate step
  } line[linewidth=2pt](-1,0)(1,0)
```

The [Hello World example](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/sketch.html#Introduction-by-example) shows how to draw a line: `line(-1,-1,-1)(2,2,2)` (you can add more points to the list).  It also shows how to compile the file: `sketch simple.sk -o simple.tex`.  Add `global { language tikz }` to your file to produce TikZ output.

This isn't a complete solution to your problem but I suspect it will point you in the right direction if you want to use Sketch.

**One caveat is that *curves* are not implemented in the current version of Sketch, so you would have to approximate the curvature of your curved segments using a number of shorter line segments.**

Comment: I think at the moment this is more of a comment than an answer. Could you maybe include an example showing how to rotate a shape like the one in the question?

Comment: Have a look in the manual http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/sketch.html#Polyline-sweeps

Comment: I added more detail.  I think it is enough to point the OP in the right direction.  If someone wants to add another answer with more detail or a different method, please go ahead.